# c# repository pattern to support normalized mongo db

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm starting to learn MongoDB and I'm trying to make a repository pattern in C# that could support a normalized data model as presented in this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models).

I do have a few questionson how I should do it.

1. Do I have to save first an object property before saving the parent object?
2. When querying, should I query first the object properties and then connect them with the parent object through code?

So far, my current repository pattern code saves and query an embedded model and i don't like it. Hope you could give me some ideas on how to make a repository pattern that supports a normalized data model. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/) shows a nice way of implementing the repository pattern in c#. The purpose if it is to hide how object a are persisted and also to limit data access code for a table or set of tables to a single place.

Typically a repository will fully populate your objects so that any collections referring to other objects are properly populated. If you have a separate repository for a parent entity usually you need to save that entity into the database before saving its children. That is unless your repository can save the parent and child objects at the same time.

The repository patter can definitely support normalization, although that typically depends on how you set up your object hierarchy and your database rather than your repository.